# why I can't do command pwd or any command in my docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was going into my container such like this

```
docker exec -t CONTAINER_ID sh
```

then I got into the container, but when I run any command such as `ls` or `pwd` it was nothing happened and freeze, anyone know why this happened ?

here is my docker-compose.yml service

```
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/Dockerfile
      args:
        - APP_NAME=myapp
    command: ./myapp
    expose:
      - 4003
```

and my Dockerfile

```
# stage 1
FROM golang:1.16-buster AS builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GOPATH /app
ENV GOBIN /go/bin

RUN mkdir -p /app/src/myapp


WORKDIR /app/src/myapp

ADD ../ /app/src/myapp

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -tags dev -o /$APP_NAME ./cmd/server/$APP_NAME

# stage 2
FROM alpine:3.14

ARG APP_NAME

WORKDIR /app/src/myapp

COPY --from=builder /$APP_NAME /app/src/myapp
```

Comment: I think that the golang image doesn't have any shell command packed in,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to specify `-i` or `--interactive` to open a Docker shell.  For example:

```sh
docker exec -i -t CONTAINER_ID sh
```